Rust nix clone cause waitpid ECHILD error
I'm using rust nix crate to clone a new process, and in the parent I use waitpid to wait child to exit. However, I met with some errors:
In parent process, child PID: 2747, parent PID 2746
In child process, child PID: 2747, parent PID: 2746
thread 'main' panicked at src/main.rs:23:32:
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ECHILD

This is my source code:


fn main() {
    let mut stack = [0u8; 1 * 1024 * 1024]; // 1 MB stack for child process

    let cb = Box::new(|| {
        println!("In child process, child PID: {}, parent PID: {}", getpid(), getppid());

        sleep(10);
        println!("Ended!");
        0
    });

    match unsafe { clone(cb, &mut stack, CloneFlags::empty(), None) } {
        Ok(pid) => {
            println!("In parent process, child PID: {}, parent PID {}", pid, getpid());
            waitpid(pid, None).unwrap();
        }
        Err(e) => {
            eprintln!("Failed to create child process: {}", e);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}

And I'm sure that when calling waitpid, the child is still running.
I don't understand why this could happen. Anything wrong with my codes?
This is my system settings:
Linux ubuntu-Virtual 6.8.0-40-generic #40~22.04.3-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Jul 30 17:30:19 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Could anyone provide some clues? I'm quite lost.

According to the waitpid man page, ECHILD _can happen for one's own child if the action for SIGCHLD is set to SIG_IGN → maybe something to look into.

@Mat Thanks but it still wont work.

Ok thanks to @Jmb, it's the signal problem.
The last parameter shall be set to Some(SIGCHLD) rather than None.
I thought this behaviour is by default, but it turns out not.
